# Countraexample on logic truth

Tags: logic

I know that the statement if $\vDash \alpha$ if and only if $\vDash \beta$ then $\vDash \alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$ is not true. But i can't find any countraexample :( Can you help me?

Comment: Let $\alpha$ be any sentence that is satisfiable but not valid and $\beta$ be its negation.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this so far?